# How to edit the "copy promotion code" text on the Whatsapp's cloud API utility template?

Tags: facebook, message, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm creating a template to sent OTP codes (want to personalize the message a bit, so not choosing the auth template). I chose the utility template to build it from scratch and everything clicks except for the "copy code" option. It has a default text "Copiar código da oferta" (which roughly translates to "copy promotion code") that's apparently impossible to edit (see images below).

[image: Message sample]

[image: Text edit is deactivated]

I know by experience that other businesses have achieved this (see images below) but no idea how
[image: example with iFood]